# ArcGIS OG Cost Matrix not iterating over all origins

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, cost-path

I am working with a large data set of property information (500K+ observations), trying to create a cost matrix to find the drive time of all points to downtown Houston. I have set my origins as the parcel point and have set my destination as a singular point in downtown Houston. I did not change any default settings when I was loading my destinations. When I solve the matrix only 125 observations are returned.

Previous posts about this subject have suggested it's a network connectivity issue. I have tried integrating my network, however that didn't change anything. I have also thought about changing the search tolerance for my origin points, but I don't think that would be a solution.

Large scale example:
[image]

Small scale example:
[image]

Purple = parcel, 
Green point = junction

Looking at the above maps, the analysis is taking place within a small area and avoiding observations which are in the same same neighborhood. Because of these two images I've determined that previous answers to this question may not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your connectivity policy allow you to turn at any vertex or is it set for end points?  It looks like all of your destinations are in a row, which could be because the network only allows you to get off that road at it's end, not necessarily where it is crossed by other roads.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching around your locations, origin as the singular point and destinations as the 500k+ observations. When loading the origin, set the TargetDestinationCount as 500k+, then solve

Comment: sorry, just gave this a shot and it did not work.